# Why does an array of all 32-bit integers require 4 GB?

Tags: memory, integer, byte, bit, 32-bit

I am struggling to understand where the 4 GB figure comes from when trying to estimate how much memory you'd need to store all 32-bit integers.

A 32-bit integer data type has 32 bits which can be set to 1 or 0 per bit. That's 2^32 possible representations. And each representation requires 32 bits, for a total of 32 * 2^32 bits required, or 2^5 * 2^32 = 2^37 bits.

And 2^37 bits is roughly 17 GB, not 4 GB.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you have a source for the 4GB figure? Your working seems reasonable at a glance.

Comment: About _"where the 4 GB figure comes from when trying to estimate "_ how are you estimating? How many individual 32-bit integers are you storing? Where does the `2^5` come from in `2^5 * 2^32 = 2^37`?

Answer (score 0):

Is your 4 GB actually 4.2 GB?

You might see the number `4,294,967,295` used as maximum value for [**32-bit integers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit).

This is because (if using as **unsigned** bytes) :

The correct formula is : `(2^32) − 1 = 4294967295`.